# error in your SQL syntax, MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE PROCEDURE pro()

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, mariadb, sql-insert, recursive-query

```
DELIMITER $$
use adventureworks
CREATE PROCEDURE pro()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 0;
    
    WHILE i <= 50 DO
        INSERT INTO salesorderheader(SalesOrderID, RevisionNumber, OrderDate)
        VALUES (i, 1, "2001-07-01 00:00:00");
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END $$
call pro()
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Works for me, using latest MariaDB 10.5. What version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a terminator after each statement. The `use` and `call` statement don’t have one.

You are switching the delimiter at the beginning of your script, so the syntax would be:

```
delimiter $$

use adventureworks$$

create procedure pro()
begin 
    ...
end$$

call pro()$$

delimiter ;
```

A more typical approach is to change the delimiter for the procedure definition only:

```
use adventureworks;

delimiter $$
create procedure pro()
begin 
    ...
end$$
delimiter ;

call pro();
```

Side note: if you are running MariaDB 10.3 or higher, you can use a recursive query instead of a loop:

```
insert into salesorderheader(SalesOrderID, RevisionNumber, OrderDate)
with cte as (
    select 1 as i 
    union all select i + 1 from cte where i < 50
)
select i, 1, '2001-07-01'
from cte
```